# Pylance "Invalid Character in token" for !pip commands

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-interactive, pylance

I am running Python 3.9.5 in interactive mode on VSCode. My first cell looks like this:

[image: pip commands giving errors]

The error is

> Invalid character in token "" Pylance

.
The code still runs fine when I press Run Cell.

How can I make Pylance ignore these commands or get rid of the errors somehow?

Extensions:

- Pylance 1021.5.1
- Python 2021.5.829140558
- Jupyter 2021.5.745244803

OS: Windows 10

Comment: This `!pip`  command generally used in `Jupyter-notebook` so you go with `pip` or `pip3` as per your requirement

Comment: Yeah, the interactive python mode runs on a Jupyter server, but pylance still interprets the file as a normal python file. Thus it gives out squiggly lines even though the code runs fine. removing the exclamation mark or changing to pip3 doesn't solve the issue..

Comment: @gunar.kroeger -This "!pip" is not a standard sentence of python, so it is recognized as an irregular sentence by "Pylance" in the ".py" file. It is recommended that you use the command "pip install module_name" in the VS Code terminal to install the required module. Also, since it successfully installed the module, you could ignore this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be reported as a warning:

```
!pip install numpy
```

This will force Pylance to ignore warnings in that line

```
!pip install numpy # type: ignore
```

[image]

This is ok if you only have a few lines, but ideally, I would like to have a single comment/annotation to disable the linter and then another comment/annotation to re-enable it, but I can't figure out how to do that, perhaps something like:

```
# type: ignore on      <<<<<<<<<< NOTE: THIS DOES NOT WORK, I JUST WISH IT DID
!pip install numpy
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install pandas
# type: ignore off     <<<<<<<<<< NOTE: THIS DOES NOT WORK, I JUST WISH IT DID
```

Comment: Even though this solution removes the Pylance warning, it has the side effect of suppressing the output. Is there a way to still view the output of a magic command? For example, when using single and double question marks: `?func_name` and `??func_name`, the output should be details about the function.